# JavaScript / AngularJS - Clean Boolean Toggling

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a group of `boolean` variable that toggles other variables to `false` if flagged as `true`.

Is there a clean pattern to this approach? Considering that the number of `boolean` variables might increase.

```js
angular.module("app", [])
  .controller("controller", function($scope) {
    $scope.a = true;
    $scope.b = false;
    $scope.c = false;

    $scope.toggleA = function() {
      $scope.a = true;
      $scope.b = false;
      $scope.c = false;
    }
    
    $scope.toggleB = function() {
      $scope.b = true;
      $scope.a = false;
      $scope.c = false;
    }
    
    $scope.toggleC = function() {
      $scope.c = true;
      $scope.b = false;
      $scope.a = false;
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="controller">
  <button ng-click="toggleA()">A is {{a}}</button>
  <button ng-click="toggleB()">B is {{b}}</button>
  <button ng-click="toggleC()">C is {{c}}</button>
</div>
```

Comment: You might want to add an `angular` tag too...as there might be something built in

Answer (score 4):

Depending on how these are used there may be many solutions, but it seems insane to have several interdependent variables. You should probably express the current state using one variable that can hold more than two values:

```js
angular.module("app", [])
  .controller("controller", function($scope) {
    $scope.current = 'a';
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="controller">
  <button ng-click="current = 'a'">A is {{ current == 'a' }}</button>
  <button ng-click="current = 'b'">B is {{ current == 'b' }}</button>
  <button ng-click="current = 'c'">C is {{ current == 'c' }}</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Why don't simply do something like this:

```js
angular.module("app", [])
  .controller("controller", function($scope) {
    $scope.x = 'a';

    $scope.toggle = function(x) {
      $scope.x = x;          
    }        
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="controller">
  <button ng-click="toggle('a')">A is {{x === 'a'}}</button>
  <button ng-click="toggle('b')">B is {{x === 'b'}}</button>
  <button ng-click="toggle('c')">C is {{x === 'c'}}</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

'You could use an array as container for your boolean and then use just one function to switch it all. Here is an example.

```js
angular.module("app", [])
  .controller("controller", function($scope) {
    $scope.keys = {
      a: true,
      b: false,
      c: false
    };

    $scope.toggle = function(change_key) {
      for (var key in $scope.keys)
        if ($scope.keys.hasOwnProperty (key))
          if (key === change_key)
            $scope.keys[key] = true;
          else
            $scope.keys[key] = false;
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="controller">
  <button ng-click="toggle('a')">A is {{keys.a}}</button>
  <button ng-click="toggle('b')">B is {{keys.b}}</button>
  <button ng-click="toggle('c')">C is {{keys.c}}</button>
</div>
```

Comment: `$scope.keys` is invalid array.

Comment: @Durga yes. sorry. Forgot to change the semicolons into commata. Thanks

Comment: @Aleksey. wow yes. Not my day. Too much PHP and json_encode (). Now it is an JS-object. Thanks again.

Comment: @wayneOS well... with `A is {{a}}` your `$scope.a` is not defined, so it's empty. I believe it should be like `A is {{keys.a}}` or something

Answer (score 0):

You can try this i am not sure what's the next step for you but it can be a good solution

```js
angular.module("app", [])
  .controller("controller", function($scope) {
    $scope.keys = [ 
             {"name":"a","value":true},
             {"name":"b","value":false},
             {"name":"c","value":false}
    ];

    $scope.toggle = function(key) {
       key.value = !key.value;
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="controller">
  <button ng-repeat="key in keys" ng-click="toggle(key)">{{key.name}} is {{key.value}}</button>
</div>
```